# Mock an api call with mocha in rspec while doing integration testing with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, mocha.js

Basically what is happening is when I'm doing the integration testing in my rspec specifications I'm testing the reset password functionality, and I'm using a third party api call to send out the email. I want to trust the third party api to send out the email and ignore the response entirely.

Here is the code that I'm using right now, but it is still sending out the email as well as failing because the call to send_password_reset (which is where the third party api call is contained) is "not" being called according to Mocha

```
before(:each) do
  @client = Factory(:user_with_clients).clients.first
end

it 'should send out the email(mock) set a temporary password and take them back to the login page' do
  # WHEN THE MOCK WAS MOVED HERE THE SPEC PASSSED
  visit '/client_portal/reset_password/new'
  fill_in 'email', with: @client.email
  click_button 'Send password reset'
  # THIS NEEDED TO BE MOVED TO THE TOP OF THE FUNCTION
  Client.expects(:send_password_reset).returns(true)
  current_path.should eq('/client_portal/login')
  page.should have_content('Check your email')
  @client.reload
  @client.tmp_password.should_not eq(nil)
end
```

I don't think posting the factories used to create this will reveal anything else, but you think that would help you help me I'll do it.

I have also tried to change the Cilent.expects to @client.expects and I still have the same issue. I'm not tied to the Mocha framework since this is actually my first mock I've ever done.

I've also read that I'm not supposed to be mocking objects in integration testing, but I don't know of a way to not send out the email when the test is called.

Just thought that I should add the controller action in there as well in case I should be changing something in there...

```
def create
    client = Client.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if client
      client.set_tmp_password
      if client.send_password_reset
        redirect_to '/client_portal/login', notice: 'Check your email for the password reset link'
      else
        redirect_to '/client_portal/login', notice: 'There was an error resetting your password. Please try one more time, and contact support if it doesn\'t work'
      end
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'No account with that email address was found'
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Im receiving this error when I run the test

```
  1) Reset a users password user is not logged in valid email address supplied should send out the email(mock) set a temporary password and take them back to the login page
     Failure/Error: Client.any_instance.expects(:send_password_reset).returns(true)
     Mocha::ExpectationError:
       not all expectations were satisfied
       unsatisfied expectations:
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<AnyInstance:Client(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, password_digest: string, signup_charge: decimal, monthly_charge: decimal, active: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, monthly_charge_day: integer, sold_by_user_id: integer, tmp_password: string)>.send_password_reset(any_parameters)
     # ./spec/requests/client_portal/reset_password_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**SOLUTION**

Using the code below from @Veraticus and moving it to the top of the spec solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not calling the `send_password_reset` method on the class; you're calling it on an instance of that class. Use this:

```
 Client.any_instance.expects(:send_password_reset).returns(true)
```

The `client` found by `Client.find_by_email` will have the expectation set up on it correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. I've added the error that I'm getting with your code, which is about the exact same as the error I was getting before. And it is still sending out the email via the third party api. I'll update this to include some more of the spec. Maybe the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: The expectation needs to be set up at the beginning of your test, before the click_button.

Comment: Well hey hey hey you'r a genious. I just had to move the any_instance code to the top of the function. My assumption (correct me if I'm wrong) is that since it was visiting the page before creating the mock that it wasn't applying the condition to the object before it was created... maybe...

Comment: That's exactly what happened. It processed the action as per normal; then you set up a new mock with a new expectation that wasn't satisfied and it exploded.